# How to check installed Mahout version?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

How can I check (in command line), what version of Mahout has been installed on a CentOS machine?

Comment: `rpm -qa|grep mahout`?

Comment: look for the mahout installed lib jars , you could get an idea of version from that. Just locate mahout and go through the results.

Comment: Thank you. I thought mahout might have some king of a "version" command, but I guess not. @MarcB, your solution seems the cleanest, if you create an answer, I will accept it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, since Mahout doesn't seem to have a command for this, I used the Linux command:

`rpm -qa | grep mahout`